# NPE when invoking Spring Service from another Spring project

Tags: java, spring

I have two spring projects wherein I have included one spring jar as a dependency in another spring project. I am getting a NPE when Autowiring the Spring service.

Spring Project 1:

```
package com.myproject.project1;

@Component
public class FileProcess() {
    @Autowired
    private DocService docService;
    public getDocuments() {
        docService.getDocumentDetails(12);
    }
}
```

Spring Project 2:

```
package com.myproject.project2;

@Component
public class DocService() {
    @Autowired
    DocumentDao docDao;
    public void getDocumentDetails(Integer id) {
        docDao.findOneDocumentById(id)
    }
}
```

I have included the jar of Spring project 2 as a dependency in Spring 1 project's pom.xml. When trying to invoke the service of the Spring 2 project, I am getting an NPE when autowiring DocService docService.

I have also set basecomponent scanning in both of my spring projects to package `com.myproject` in spring.xml using `<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject" />`

here is my spring.xml

Comment: Can you add your spring.xml code?

Comment: Probably the problem sis in a way how you set basecomponent, can you add this to the question ?

Comment: here is my spring.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

 <context:annotation-config />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject" />
</beans>

Comment: Edit your question to add it. Not in comments.

Comment: i updated it in questions section, it's not showing up

Comment: it may be getting NPE due to   DocumentDao docDao; can you provide that class ? Just check that and it may resolve your error.